# Determine if local cache is stale for a single item in Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

In the [Redux Async](http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/AsyncActions.html) example there is a function called `shouldFetch` which takes in `(state, subreddit)` and returns whether you should fetch the items in the given `subreddit`.

How can you do the same thing reliably but for a single item? Meaning a function that takes `shouldFetch(state, subreddit, id)` and returns `Boolean`.

The real issue is how do you keep the `metadata` of when each item was fetched? We are storing when the list was fetched in `lastUpdated` but not when each item was last updated.

You will need to:
1. Determine if item is even in the cache (store)
2. Determine whether this current item is currently being fetched (either through the list fetch, or through individual fetch)
3. Determine whether the item is stale or not.

Is there any good way to implement this besides building a client-side database for lastUpdated/isFetching ?

Answer (score 0):

> How can you do the same thing reliably but for a single item? Meaning a function that takes shouldFetch(state, subreddit, id) and returns Boolean.

As the shouldFetchPosts function in your link, you have to create your own function which checks if some metadata has something or not. This part is not about redux, it is about your metadata, how you shaped your data on your redux store or if the metadata you need is avialable in your server response.

So you have to create a function which takes some data and checks the given data for the logic you wrote in the function body.

> The real issue is how do you keep the metadata of when each item was fetched? We are storing when the list was fetched in lastUpdated but not when each item was last updated.

Do you mean that you are updating your list items and you don't make a server request for the updated list ? If not, if you are just sending a request to update item and maybe updating the item in your redux state too, this shounds okay. Since your aplication is a SPA , if you are sure your data has changed on the server, you can easily change your redux state and might not make a server-request.

> You will need to: 1. Determine if item is even in the cache (store) 2. Determine whether this current item is currently being fetched (either through the list fetch, or through individual fetch) 3. Determine whether the item is stale or not.

Now here is my idea, you actually should check if some data is stale or not from your components and if something is being fetched you shouldn't allow your user to trigger refetching, again if some data is not stale, you can easily make a function in your component which decides if a user-triggered action is necessary.

Moving all of this logic to redux actions makes your redux files ugly. However you can shape your redux state, improve it as you go and check some metadata from state to make desicions.

Comment: You haven't posted any suggestion on how to actually do it, but rather outlined the points I have already mentioned in my question. I'm looking for a possible real solution to the problem of determining whether the app should fetch a single item from the server (and not an array of items)

Comment: Sorry dude, I appreciate your help but your post is of no help for me. I'm looking for a real life solution, with either a specific way to structure the `redux` store for the items collection, or some technique to use such as long  api throttling in order to handle this situation and you have provided none of these.

Comment: For example, you wrote `So you have to create a function which takes some data and checks the given data for the logic you wrote in the function body.`. Well that is pretty obvious, but I'm looking for an implementation, not the overview.

Comment: Try to write vanilla react components with data being managed by react state , props etc. Then see how you can get rid of that by utilizing redux state, using as if it is a react state ( this.state = {}, this.setState ). So that you will understand why to use redux. This is all I can help. Now I have no time, tomorrow I might have time to write some code for you.

Answer (score 0):

I actually built a [redux-cached-api-middleware](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-cached-api-middleware) package that helps to interact with API in a cached way. It preserves the fetch completion timestamp that can help to determine if the cache is stale or not. For example:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import api from 'redux-cached-api-middleware';
import Items from './Items';
import Error from './Error';

class ExampleApp extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchData();
  }

  render() {
    const { result } = this.props;
    if (!result) return null;
    if (result.fetching) return <div>Loading...</div>;
    if (result.error) return <Error data={result.errorPayload} />;
    if (result.successPayload) return <Items data={result.successPayload} />;
    return <div>No items</div>;
  }
}

ExampleApp.propTypes = {
  fetchData: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  result: PropTypes.shape({}),
};

const CACHE_KEY = 'GET/items';

const enhance = connect(
  state => ({
    result: api.selectors.getResult(state, CACHE_KEY),
  }),
  dispatch => ({
    fetchData() {
      return dispatch(
        api.actions.invoke({
          method: 'GET',
          headers: { Accept: 'application/json' },
          endpoint: 'https://my-api.com/items/',
          cache: {
            key: CACHE_KEY,
            strategy: api.cache
              .get(api.constants.CACHE_TYPES.TTL_SUCCESS)
              .buildStrategy({ ttl: 10 * 60 * 1000 }), // 10 minutes
          },
        })
      );
    },
  })
);

export default enhance(ExampleApp);
```

This component uses one of caching strategies, to determine if resource should be re-fetched when `this.props.fetchData();` function is invoked.

You could also provide a custom `shouldFetch` function if you have a more complex way to determine cache validity:

```
const enhance = connect(
  state => ({
    result: api.selectors.getResult(state, CACHE_KEY),
  }),
  dispatch => ({
    fetchData() {
      return dispatch(
        api.actions.invoke({
          method: 'GET',
          headers: { Accept: 'application/json' },
          endpoint: 'https://my-api.com/items/',
          cache: {
            key: CACHE_KEY,
            strategy: api.cache   
            shouldFetch({ state }) { // CachedApiState object
              // Define your logic when the resource should be re-fetched
              return true;
            }
          },
        })
      );
    },
  })
);
```

* The `CachedApiState` object consists of fields:

```
{
  fetching: boolean, // is fetching in progress
  fetched: boolean, // was any fetch completed
  error: boolean, // was last response an error
  timestamp: ?number, // last response timestamp
  successPayload: ?any, // last success response payload
  errorPayload: ?any, // last error response payload
}
```